# Prevent user from installing program in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, group-policy

There are 5 Win 7 machines. All the machines have one password protected Administrator account and one Standard user account. These machines are connected to a router.

All the machines have been blocked to access USB media drives and CD/DVD drive. Standard users on every machine is allowed to install software by using Administrator password only(Elevated privileges group policy).

So, for the start, I followed these links http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-stop-users-from-installing-new-programs-in/59cfe502-dc5c-4bd4-85fe-a7e5f89fe1e0?auth=1 and http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-prevent-users-from-installing-programs-in-windows-7 to edit some Group Policies.

However, even after following the process, I notice that it is possible to install applications using shared folder. Disabling sharing altogether is not to be done because it remains the only way to share files among computers. However, I wish to stop installation through this.

How to make this way of installation require password or stop the installation altogether?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a group policy you can setup that will only allow approved programs to be ran.  This means any program not on the list ( an installer ) could not even be ran.  You should do that.

Comment: Are you sure window installer services "msiserver" is OFF!! and you remove it from startup services too?!

Comment: @narzan : I have not made any setting in the services.msc. Will turning it OFF prevent it from installing programs? However, is it not possible to install with elevated privileges?

Comment: Turn it OFF will prevent anyone from installing any programs, but you still can setup programs from dos! or using other service, give it a try, simple way ;)